# unable to fully retrieve text in php from ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

HTML Code

```
<form name='form' method='post'>
  <textarea name='ckeditor'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save' />
<form>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).submit(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

 $editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData();

//alert($editor);

  $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url : "someurl",
     data : "full_text="+$editor,
     success = function (response) {
         alert(response);
     }
  });
});
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php 
  print_r($_POST["full_text"];
?>
```

when alert is used inside java script my full text is shown. But when used print_r function of php only two or three lines of text is shown.

If i have three paragraph text alert display all three paragraph but php shows only two lines. below is the image for more detail

First image shows alert inside javascript before submitting.

Second Image shows alert response from php page
[image: alert of textarea inside javascript]

[image: alert from ajax]

Comment: Have you tried to change the line that contains data = "full_text="+$editor to data : {full_text: $editor}?

Comment: yes i have tried. Still no result. but i discovered that if use only print_r($_POST); it shows full text

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` would be easier for a simple post request.

```
$.post("someurl", {full_text: $editor}, function(response){
  alert(response);
})
```